# How can I pass the pid information of ss into kill

Tags: node.js, linux

I am working on a Linux application server that needs to be able to kill all inbound SSH connections from a specific IP address or addresses.

I can use `ss` to list the inbound SSH connections by using

```
sudo ss -p | grep -i -c -E 'ssh.*${host}'
```

which  produces output that looks like

```
tcp    ESTAB    0        60              xxx.xxx.xxx.111:ssh        my.server.ip:64938          users:(("sshd",pid=2089
,fd=3),("sshd",pid=2038,fd=3))
```

This shows that the .111 client has two open SSH sockets with PIDs 2089 and 2038. But the format appears to be just text with some parenthesies.

How can I pass or pipe these PIDs into `kill` so I can end those specific sshd processes, but leave other sshd processes open?

The application server is running on Node.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` and its build-in `system()` function:

```
ss -p | grep :ssh | awk -F, '{print $2 }' | awk -F= '{system("kill -9 " $2) }'
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good start, but it is only grabbing the first PID for each `ss` entry. In my example above `awk -F, '{print $2 }'` shows `pid=2089`, but misses the second `pid=2038`.  It looks like this PID is provided as `awk -F '{print $5}'`. But for my scenaior, there are variable number of PIDs associated with each connection. Can I get awk to detect all of them?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on the answer from @marekful.

His solution only grabbed the first pid of each `ss` output, but each connection could have one or more associated pids. To get all of them, I used the following code:

```
sudo ss -p 
   | grep -i  -E 'ssh.*.111' 
   | gawk '{ 
       while (match($0, /pid=([0-9]+)/, ary)) {
          print 'killing', ary[1]; 
          system("sudo kill -9 " ary[1]);
          $0 = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH);
       } 
     }'
```